# Can't surf to WCF REST service from browser

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-rest

Consider this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICreditCardExtractor
{       
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string CoolAction();
}
```

I've directed a new app in my IIS to the artifacts, and able to surf to files.
However, when I try to invoke the `CoolAction` (by browsing to `http://localhost/MySvc/CreditCardExtractor.svc/CoolAction`)

I get

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

This is my `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
         <!--pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/-->
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
        </protocolMapping>
        <!--added service behaviour configuration-->
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService1.CreditCardExtractor">
                <endpoint 
                    address="" 
                    binding="webHttpBinding"  
                    contract="WcfService1.ICreditCardExtractor" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment  
                aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    ....
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've *defined* your endpoint behavior - but you haven't **applied** it to the service endpoint - try to update your configuration to:

```
<services>
    <service name="WcfService1.CreditCardExtractor">
        <endpoint 
            address="" 
            behaviorConfiguration="web"  -- add this line here!!
            binding="webHttpBinding"  
            contract="WcfService1.ICreditCardExtractor" />
    </service>
</services>
```